# Issues in using lda for vowpal wabbit

Tags: topic-modeling

I am trying to use the vowpal wabbit lda model. But I am having very bad results. I think there is something wrong with the process I am doing. I have this vocabulary size of 100000.

I run the code like this

vw --data train.txt --lda 50 --lda_alpha 0.1 --lda_rho 0.1 --lda_D 262726  -b 20 -pions.dat --readable_model wordtopics.dat

Now I was expecting the wordtopics.dat file to contain the topic proportions for those 100000 words but it looks that this word topics.dat file is very huge contains like 1048587 lines.

I think it is because of b = 20, and the lines at the end are like having uniform probability distribution.

However, when I look at the topics obtained they do not make sense at all. So I think something is wrong. What could go wrong guys?

Answer (score 0):

Not answering your question, but guys at Columbia University Applied Data Science have made a [helper](https://github.com/columbia-applied-data-science/rosetta/blob/master/examples/vw_helpers.md) to work with VW's LDA, especially on viewing the results.

Also try to use `--passes` option so VW result can be better over some number of training.